# How to get user name from user id in React.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, redux

I have created this schema with mongoose

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const QuestionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'users'
    },
    question:{
        type:String
    },
    name:{
        type:String,
    },
    answerd:[
        {
            user:{
                type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref:'users'
            }
        }
    ]
})

module.exports = Question = mongoose.model('question',QuestionSchema);
```

In my global state (REDUX) I have the state

```
const initialState = {
    questions:[],
    question:null,
    loading:true,
    error:{}
};
```

The element questions store question object which contains the name of the user who made the question, the question itself, and people who have answered.

Some where in a .js file I can get the id of users who have answered by simply
`question.buzzed.map(user=> <h1> {user._id} </h1>)`,
but how is possible to get this user name, I also have a schema for user which have attributes such as name, id, ... etc

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `populate` method. It is like `join` in SQL for mongoose, because it connects your answer to the user collection. Based on your code, it could look like this :

```
Question.find({}).populate("answerd")
```

or something like this:

```
Question.find().populate({ path: 'answerd', select: 'username' });
```

For more information please read the [populate documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

Answer (score 0):

U can use $lookup.

```
var aggregate = [
  {
    $unwind: "$answerd"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      localField: "user",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "user"
    }
  }
];

Questions.aggregate(aggregate, function(err, users) {


})
```